# Convexity and Superadditivity in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

In 1-dimension convex function are superadditive on $\mathbb{R}^+$ with $f(0) \leq 0$ (easy proof)

How to prove superadditivity of convex function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \geq 2$? (if possible?)

Convex function : For $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ if f satisfies $f(\lambda a +(1-\lambda)b) \leq \lambda f(a) + (1-\lambda) f(b)$

Comment: It's still not true for $\Bbb R^2$. Consider the function $f(x,y)=x^2$ which is clearly convex.

Answer (score 4):

It's not even true that a convex function is superadditive on $\Bbb R$. Consider the function $f(x)=x^2$, we have 
$$
f(1+(-1)) = 0 < 2 = f(1) + f(-1).
$$

Comment: I think you are using the wrong definition of the convex function.

Comment: @R.Arora How is $x^2$ not a convex function?

Comment: @R.Arora You claimed that convex functions on $\Bbb R$ are superadditive. I gave a counter example saying that a convex function need __not__ be superadditive .

Comment: I didn't use any property at all, just pure calculation.

Comment: @R.Arora I wasn't using the definition of convexity. Here's what I said: 1) $f(x)=x^2$ __is__ a convex function. 2) $f$ __is not__ superadditive. 3) Hence your claim is false.

Comment: I'm saying for the third times that $f$ is __not__ superadditive... When have I ever mentioned subadditive anyway?

Comment: I did one mistake in question, it is for positive real number.